# How exactly do hallucinations work in Starcraft 2?

Tags: starcraft-2

I heard that halucinations take twice the damage as normal units. Are they different in any other way? Armor, speed ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In addition to taking double damage, they also don't *output* any damage, which is probably obvious. I can't find any references to them having otherwise different stats such as lower speed or not benefiting from upgrades. (**Edit:** tzenes says in the comments they do not benefit from armor; I haven't tested it.)

According to [this site](http://starcraft.wikia.com/wiki/Hallucination), they are destroyed instantly by a psionic storm.  Also, detectors can spot them, so I'd *guess* if a detector was in the area their priority for the AI to attack them will be low.

Otherwise, to your enemies, they seem exactly the same as normal units.

In particular, for you they provide sight, so they can be used for scouting or spotting.

Comment: Its worth noting that in beta hallucinated Colossus used to break force fields.  This is no longer the case.  Additionally, they do not gain benefit from armor upgrades.

Comment: Hallucinated Immortals appear to have their hardened shield as well, though I'm unsure if damage above 10 gets reduced to 10 (as per normal immortal shields) or to 20 (10 x2 for being a hallucination)

Comment: @Raven its not reduced but the animation does show up as if it was

Comment: I've noticed that just because a detector shows which are hallucinations, your units will still auto-target them the same.